# Type of Tree With Somewhat Squarish Fruit

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I live in the SF Bay Area and am trying to identify a tree on my street. It's the fruit that is confusing me -- does anyone know what this fruit is?
It's not a rare tree -- there are at least several more on the surrounding streets.

Mature leaves are about 6" long and greater.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you put something in to indicate scale?

Comment: Looks like the regional government maps every street tree: https://data.sfgov.org/City-Infrastructure/Street-Tree-Map/337t-q2b4 Maybe you can find it!

Comment: A photo of the bark/trunk would be useful too, and if you can break off a leaf and see if there is any latex that oozes out of the wound.  Unless of course you found it in the street tree inventory.

Comment: Thanks everyone! -- I'm the poster. I added some pictures of the bark and fruit earlier today but the edit did not go through. I don't care for the comment policies here so will be deleting my account.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a persimmon — your first image is of immature fruit.

Compare with:

[image: immature Persimmon from UC Davis — Fruit and Nut Education]
[UC Davis — Fruit and Nut Education](http://fruitandnuteducation.ucdavis.edu/fruitnutproduction/Persimmon/Persimmon_FFdev/Fuyu_Dev/)

[Google Image link](https://images.app.goo.gl/8cBYPnxGLTG5S5tcA)

Comment: Good job... I was thinking about persimmon too, but for whatever reason could not find a picture of those leathery sepals.  Now I know.  The bark would have been distinctive.